# MariaDB SQL Error

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to insert a value into a column using a input button

but keep getting a error, I need to indicate which user I want to update

this is my query

```
INSERT INTO tbl_users (onGGCCpage) VALUES (1) WHERE user_id=$user_id
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Error: INSERT INTO tbl_users (onGGCCpage) VALUES (1) WHERE user_id=22
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user_id=22' at line 1
```

Comment: you want to `UPDATE` a user, not `INSERT` a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Insert have no where condition

```
INSERT INTO tbl_users (onGGCCpage) VALUES (1)
```

Could be you need  update

```
UPDATE  tbl_users  set onGGCCpage =1
WHERE user_id=$user_id
```